# What is the JPA best practice for storing both a relationship and its primary key?

Tags: jpa

Long setup to this question; please bear with me.

In JPA, you can store a reference to another entity using (for example) a `@ManyToOne`-annotated relationship:

```
// In Wheel.java
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id", nullable = false)
private Car car;
```

Under the covers this is usually implemented by a `JOIN`.  If you looked in the table to which `Wheel` maps, you would find a column likely named something like `carId` or `car_id`, and that column would be a foreign key "pointing at", say, a `car` table's primary key.  Rudimentary stuff.

Sometimes (when serializing the root entity over the wire, for example), you just want the key itself:

```
// In Wheel.java
@Column(name = "car_id", nullable = false)
private int carId;
```

This is also fine.

Typically you don't see both of these.

When you *do* see both of these, one of them is marked using the by-convention-because-the-spec-has-a-hole-in-it modifiers `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`:

```
// In Wheel.java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Car car;

@Column(name = "car_id", nullable = false)
private int carId;
```

Once you do this, you now have to make sure that any setter methods that *were* on the relationship are removed:

```
// In Wheel.java
public Car getCar() {
  return this.car;
}

// No longer appropriate now that the relationship is read-only
// public void setCar(final Car car) {
//   this.car = car;
// }
```

You do have to make sure the `carId` variable can be set, however, and, when it is changed, you have to make sure the `Car` reference is `null`ed out, since it will no longer refer to the right `Car`:

```
// In Wheel.java
public int getCarId() {
  return this.carId;
}

public void setCarId(final int newId) {
  final int old = this.getCarId();
  this.carId = newId;
  if (old != newId) {
    this.car = null;
  }
}
```

And now the question:

*REALLY*?  Is this the best or only way to always have the primary key present for a given relationship along with the possibility of "inflating" the relationship itself into its target?

Comment: Not an answer, but why don't you make the carId non insertable and non updatable instead? You could at least set the carId to the correct value when setting the car. And you would keep your object model cleaner.

Comment: I'm more interested in the case where as little information as possible is present in the entity.  If I load the `Car` to get its primary key, then I don't really need the `carId` column at all (because I can always get to it via the `Car#getId()` method).

Comment: Can you tell me a case when you need the carId? You might be just looking for the reference of the entity (proxy), which you can obtain via the method EntityManager.getReference().

Comment: Sure.  I'm thinking of a case where a JPA entity is serialized to XML.  I want to avoid loading the `Car` just to get its `id` to send over the wire.  Does that make sense?